# Are receptacles protected when downstream from ungrounded GFCI?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci, grounding

I have an ungrounded circuit in my house with three-wire grounded receptacles.  If I install a GFCI, will the downstream receptacles be protected even if the GFCI is ungrounded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely, as long as you place the load wires going to the downstream receptacles onto the LOAD terminals of the GFCI receptacle.

A GFI does NOT need an equipment grounding conductor to function properly. In fact, using a GFI at the beginning of the circuit is what will allow you to legally and safely use 3-prong receptacles downstream. Thing is, this does not create an equipment ground for equipment protection for things such as surge suppressors.

By code you are supposed to label any non-grounding downstream receptacles "No equipment ground present".

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of receptacles protected by a single GFI?

Comment: From checking various seemingly reputable online sources, as well as checking my Leviton GFCI, it seems there is no limit on the number of outlets  you can protect.  Bonus advice: the cheap GFCI testers won't trip the GFCI if they're not grounded.  I thought I got a bad GFCI until I realized this.

Comment: There is no limit technically. We typically limit load side devices to 5-6. Every device will have a tiny amount of leakage, so with too many on the load side there is an increased chance of nuisance tripping.